# What does 'environment: &environment' mean in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose

I found [this project](https://github.com/ukd1/toshi-testnet-faucet/blob/master/docker-compose.yml.sample) while doing some research. I noticed this line inside the Docker Compose sample file:

`environment: &environment`

So I wonder what it actually means? What is the use case for this?

I tried to find it in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#environment), but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: It is when you want to reference the same config for other services in the yml file.
`&` is for the definition, while you use `*` when you want to use it.

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields

Comment: Thank you @ValerianPereira. That's helpful.

Comment: @ValerianPereira You shloud make that and answer, so it's better visible for future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is when you want to reference the same config for other services in the yml file. `&` is for the definition, while you use `*` to refer to it.

Example Snippet, where `&default-logging` is the definition block and referred to down in the `service` and `db` block using `*`

```
version: '3.4'
x-logging:
  &default-logging
  options:
    max-size: '12m'
    max-file: '5'
  driver: json-file

services:
  web:
    image: myapp/web:latest
    logging: *default-logging
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    logging: *default-logging
```

Doc: docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields